# Filtering out the data grouping by id and some condition

Tags: sql, group-by, having-clause

I have a requirement where I am getting data with Sql like below

```
someid  | passengertype  | somename |
--------+----------------+-----------
123     | 3              | abc      |
123     | 6              | zxc      |
111     | 4              | qwe      |
111     | 6              | poi      |
222     | 2              | lkj      |
563     | 1              | uyt      |
563     | 2              | mnb      |
563     | 6              | oiu      |
```

I want to select only records grouping by someid where passengertype not either 3 and 6. ie whenever for someid if passengertype contains only 3 or 6 then don't select that id, if 3 or 6 exists with other passengerid's then select. The required output should be:

```
someid  | passengertype  | somename |
--------+----------------+-----------
111     | 4              | qwe      |
111     | 6              | poi      |
222     | 2              | lkj      |
563     | 1              | uyt      |
563     | 2              | mnb      |
563     | 6              | oiu      |
```

Comment: If you want the original rows, then `group by` does not seem appropriate.  That would reduce the number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists` . . . twice:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.someid = t.someid and t2.passengertype = 3
                 ) or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.someid = t.someid and t2.passengertype = 6
                 ) ;
```

If you only wanted the `someid` values that meet this condition, then aggregation would be appropriate:

```
select someid
from t
group by someid
having sum(case when passengertype = 3 then 1 else 0 end) = 0 or
       sum(case when passengertype = 6 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the analytical function as dollows:

```
Select * from
(Select t.*,
       Count(*) over (partition by id) as total_cnt,
       Count(case when passenger_type in (3,6) then 1 end) over(partirion by id) as target_cnt
  From your_table t) t
 Where total_cnt != target_cnt
```